# grails popups and parent

Tags: javascript, grails, popup

I'm running Grails 2.3.3 and creating a popup window in order to select an item of data to be used in a following action.

What I'm struggling with is being able to go back to the parent web page once I have completed the popup operation.

Here is the html code to create the popup from a button on the parent window:

```
<button class = "buttons" onclick="createPopup()" name = "multiFileUpload">Multi File VideoOrig</button>
```

The js createPopup() has a popup URL creation call:

```
littleWindow = window.open("http://localhost:9000/HomeVu1//picturesNWShr/setMFUVideoTemplatePU", "littleWindow", "location=no,width=320,height=200");
```

Where the action 'setMFUVideoTemplatePU' is defined in the 'picturesNWShr' controller.

Also the 'setMFUVideoTemplatePU'  view contains a button that enables the user to move on to the next phase of the process having completed the task within the popup - see:

```
<g:actionSubmit class="buttons" action="multiFileUpload" value="${message(code: 'default.button.continue.label', default: 'Continue')}" />
```

Where the 'Continue' button will bring up the 'multiFileUpload' view. The problem is that this view is displayed in the popup window rather than the main parent window as required.

How do I force the new view to appear in the parent window - do i simply have to delete the popup?

-mike

Comment: Have you considered using a modal for this? [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) is an example of popping up a modal div using Twitter Bootstrap. No one in 2015 likes pop up windows ;-)

Comment: or jquery-ui dialog  box